# How to highlight certain parts of my documents using indicators (>*<)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to highlight certain parts of my Word documens using indicators (>*<).

```
Sub subSearch()
fkt_Search ">", "<", False
End Sub

Function fkt_Search(strStart As String, strEnd As String, Optional bInclude As Boolean = False)
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngText As Range
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
Set rngText = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
rngText.Collapse wdCollapseStart
With rng.Find
    .Format = False
    .Text = strStart
    .Execute
    Do While .Found = True
        rngText.SetRange rng.Start, rng.End
        rng.SetRange rng.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End
        .Execute FindText:=strEnd, Forward:=True
        If .Found = False Then Exit Function
        rngText.SetRange rngText.Start, rng.End
        If bInclude = True Then
            rngText.Select
            rngText.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        ElseIf bInclude = False Then
            rngText.SetRange rngText.Start + Len(strStart), rngText.End - Len(strEnd)
            rngText.Select
            rngText.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        End If
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Execute FindText:=strStart, Forward:=True
    Loop
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
End With
End Function
```

With a smaller number of operations, Word does not crash; however, it does *sometimes* crash, for example, when the indicator is part of a table.

Comment: I notice `With rng.Find` but I see you change `rng` in what follows. I could imagine that that upsets Word. Try it without the `With`.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. But that returns the error 'invalid use of property'

Comment: Great Mic. Please read the documentation about With. Without With you must write the object explicitly, so for example, instead of `.Execute` you must write `rng.Find.Execute` etc.

Comment: Why are you making things complicated when you can use Find to do a wildcard search for  ">*<"?

Comment: When it 'crashes', what is the error given and on which line?

Comment: Will do, Paul - thanks. @JMP doesnt return any error. Timothy, cause then you cant highlight the results

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a wildcard search, no code required.

[image]